# how should I fix While True loop repeating and stopping unwantedly (Roblox)

Tags: lua, 3d, roblox

I am trying to make a part duplicate then delete the duplication script with the new part without deleting the script in the old part, this is in Roblox studio.

This is my code

```
local block = script.Parent


while true do
    local xrange = math.random(-250,250)
    local zrange = math.random(-250,250)
    local item = block:Clone()
    item.Parent = game.Workspace
    item.Position = Vector3.new(xrange,.5,zrange)
    item["Block Script"]:Destroy()
    game.ReplicatedStorage.ItemCount.Value = game.ReplicatedStorage.ItemCount.Value + 1
    wait(1)
end
```

The problem is that it runs as if it is supposed to duplicate 3 times for every loop and rather than creating 1 new part each second, it creates 3 parts. The main issue is that sometimes 1 of the 3 new parts won't have the other script that I have inside the parts, making the part a useless part that causes problems.

Does anyone see a problem?
You can also comment if you want more clarification.

If this is just an error or cannot be solved through the information given, I can probably work around but please comment if you need my clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its duplicating 3 times because you are destroying the script last.. what you should try doing is:

1- creating a new folder on workspace ( going to call it "**blocks**" for example )

2- making the block and script of the block as the children of the "blocks" folder

3- and placing this code on the script:

```
local block = game.workspace."**blocks**".(Your part name)


while true do
    local xrange = math.random(-250,250)
    local zrange = math.random(-250,250)
    local item = block:Clone()
    item.Parent = game.Workspace
    item.Position = Vector3.new(xrange,.5,zrange)
    game.ReplicatedStorage.ItemCount.Value = game.ReplicatedStorage.ItemCount.Value + 1
    wait(1)
end
```

If this does not work you can reply to this comment.